# Sorting CKRecord returns "Expected Types"

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

Why this code returns Expected Types on the $1 symbol?

```
private func sorting(records: [CKRecord]) -> [CKRecord] {
    if ascendingSorting {
        return records.sorted {
            $0.value(forKey: "name") as! String < $1.value(forKey: "name") as! String
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

But if I change "<" to ">" everything goes well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a `()` and a default `return` statement if the `if condition` doesn't trigger, check out the code below.

```
private func sorting(records: [CKRecord]) -> [CKRecord] {
if ascendingSorting {
    return records.sorted {
        ($0.value(forKey: "name") as! String) < ($1.value(forKey: "name") as! String)
    }
}
//Missing return in a function expected to return '[CKRecord]'
return [] 
}
```

Comment: That's not the problem here.

Comment: perhaps i miss understood , could you explain @Dharmesh

Comment: OP is getting an error with `$0.value(forKey: "name") as! String < $1.value(forKey: "name") as! String`

Comment: ahh ok I understood.. :)

Comment: @Dharmesh hehe it's ok

Comment: @MohmmadS that is! Adding () made this error go away. How do you know this and why this error doesn't appear with opposite sign? This code not full so adding return [] not necessary in my case.

Comment: @wm.p1us i am not 100% sure but i think it's about mathematic operations priorities

Comment: but < and > should be of the same priority... ok I suppose it is looks like a bug

Comment: @wm.p1us it could be as i said i am not 100% of the reason